# How to add the next most recent entry to my query, in some other way?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get info for the next most recent entry based on the ID and location and add that to the query I am running. Not the second most recent entry in the table, only the previous entry based on the ID.

I'm not sure if this is possible or I just can't figure out how to do it or even which direction I should go.

Here is how the previous programmer did it:

```
SELECT -- blah blah blah
       , (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(id AS VARCHAR) + '~' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,  creation_date,   120)
          FROM header hdr2 
          WHERE hdr2.id < hdr.id 
                AND hdr2.location = hdr.location 
          ORDER BY hdr2.id DESC) AS "prev_info"
FROM header hdr 
/*blah blah blah*/
```

I understand why he wanted to use only a single sub query and tried to put everything into that one column, but I'm trying to optimize this and I would like to do it in some other,easier and more efficient, way.

I feel like the answer is staring me in the face, but I just can't reach out and grasp it. If I need to explain myself any more, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: use `IFNULL(MAX(hdr2.id), 0)` instead of `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY hdr2.id DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `outer apply`:

```
select  -- blah blah blah
,       prev_info.*
from    header hdr 
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 id
        ,       creation_date
        from    header hdr2 
        where   hdr2.id < hdr.id 
                and hdr2.location = hdr.location 
        order by
                hdr2.id desc
        ) as prev_info
```

Comment: This performs exactly how I needed it to. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work if you want to use ROW_NUMBER:

```
With rownumbers as 
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by location ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownumber,
    id, location
  FROM header 
)
SELECT id, location from rownumbers
WHERE rownumber = 2
```

Is that easier to read?  I'd say it depends on the reader.  Is that more efficient?  I'd have to see the execution plans.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a cross apply to get all the columns at once.

```
SELECT -- blah blah blah
FROM header hdr 
  cross apply(
          SELECT TOP 1
            hdr2.*
          FROM header hdr2 
          WHERE hdr2.id < hdr.id 
                AND hdr2.location = hdr.location 
          ORDER BY hdr2.id DESC
) AS prev_info
/*blah blah blah*/
```

Does the same thing as the subquery in the select you have except allows more than one column to be returned so you don't have to parse out everything from one concatenated column.

Comment: To clarify, the cross apply is like using an inner join.  Returns nothing for headers that have no previous id with the same location.  The outer apply that Andomar suggested behaves like a left outer join.